# Pytest - ImportError: cannot import name '' from partially initialized module 'app.api.v2.auth' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, importerror, attributeerror

I was writing functional tests for my API calls, which I had tested manually. But running test from pytest shows these errors.

```
from .auth import RxRequestForm
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'RxRequestForm' from partially initialized module 'app.api.v2.auth' (most likely due to a circular import)
====================================================================================== short test summary info =======================================================================================
ERROR test_prescription.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

The file structure is exactly as mentioned in the code -> app.api.v2.auth and RxRequestForm has been defined inside it as

```
class RxRequestForm(BaseModel):
    orderid: str
    fileid: str
```

I've tested the api multiple times and it works fine, but testing it using pytest causes the error. Even if I change the test, it still gets stuck with some other imports. I am using python 3.10.6

Comment: Do you have a minimum verifiable example that shows the behavior? It's hard to say anything useful about code that actually shows the problem.

Comment: Normally, this happens when you do a ```from .auth import RxRequestForm```,  in auth.py,  you have something that imports something from the original file.    What does ```auth.py``` look like?